# Comparing dataframe rows each other applying a specific function on columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as this:

```
d = {'Item':['x','y','z','x','z','x'], 'strings' : ['abcd', 'abs', 'abcs', 'adbc','aaaa','abc'], 'type' : ['type1','type1','type1','type2','type2','type1']}

  Item Strings   type
0    x  abcd  type1
1    y   abs  type1
2    z  abcs  type1
3    x  adbc  type2
4    z  aaaa  type2
5    x   abc  type1
```

I grouped this dataframe by Item, with this `df.groupby('Item')`.

I have this function:

```
def get_mismatch(str1: str, str2: str):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1 if y[0] != y[1] else x, zip(str1, str2), 0)
```

that allow me to get the number of character that differs between two strings.

Now I would apply get_mismatch function for each group on the Strings columns, when the `type` column is different.

How can I do this?

Thank you

**UPDATE**
**UPDATE 1**

My expected output is:

| Item | #mismatch | String_1 | String_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 3 | abcd | adbc |
| x | 2 | abc | adbc |
| z | 3 | abcs | aaaa |

Comment: "apply get_mismatch function for each group on the Strings columns, when the type column is different." What does this mean? You have two type1 for x and only one type2. Which are you comparing? Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Yes you're right..I will update the post sooner

Comment: @giupardeb Shouldn't the row `5    x   abc  type1`  be somehow in your result? What about Item `y` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely you're right. I forgot this row, I upgrade the table. Regarding item `y`, it will be removed, because in the original dataframe doesn't exist any other `y` Item

Comment: @giupardeb Are there only two types possible or more?

Comment: @AndrejKesely only two types

Answer (score 0):

Use custom function with `itertools.product` for all combinations between different types:

```
from  itertools import product
from functools import reduce

def get_mismatch(str1: str, str2: str):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1 if y[0] != y[1] else x, zip(str1, str2), 0)

def f(x):
    a = x.loc[x['type'].eq('type1'), 'strings']
    b = x.loc[x['type'].eq('type2'), 'strings']
    out = [(get_mismatch(d, e), d, e) for d, e in product(a, b)]
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['#mismatch', 'String_1','String_2'])

df = df.groupby('Item').apply(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
  Item #mismatch String_1 String_2
0    x         3     abcd     adbc
1    x         2      abc     adbc
2    z         3     abcs     aaaa
```